# Nextjs: multiple dispatch and Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
Promise.all([
        await dispatch(a()), 
        await dispatch(b()), 
        await dispatch(c()), 
        await dispatch(d())
    ]).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

And I get this log:

```
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: undefined
3: undefined
```

I want to get this data with `Promise` and I have to use `await`

Comment: `await dispatch` is unneeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Promise.all will resolve after all async inside it are resolved so you dont need to await inside it as its an implicit await so remove the await fom inside the promis.all and check again.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [a,b,c,d] = await Promise.all([
        dispatch(a()), 
        dispatch(b()), 
        dispatch(c()), 
        dispatch(d())
    ]).then().catch();
```